# jQuery scrollTop() - works only on Firefox not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scrolltop, affix

I have latest browsers versions and my code is simply:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$('#page-content').css('min-height',$(window).height()+'px');
console.log($('html').scrollTop());
if (  $('html').scrollTop() > 1 ) {

$('.nav-header').css({'position':'fixed','top':'40px','border-radius':'0 0 0 0','width':$('.nav-header').parent().width()-1+'px'});

}
if ( $('html').scrollTop() == 0 ) {

$('.nav-header').css({'position':'relative','top':'0px','border-radius':'5px 5px 0 0','width':$('.nav-header').parent().width()-1+'px'});

}

});
```

On firefox everythings ok, but in Chrome it doesn't works, i'm unable to console log scrollTop() in chrome, nothing in console :(

HERE IS THE [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6p2aJ/1/)
check it first on Firefox then in Chrome :(

Comment: Share your HTML or create a fiddle

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop()` ???

Comment: $('html').scrollTop() always gives me zero (Chrome). Are you sure, you want to use it? For detecting scroll position you should use $(window).scrollTop()

Comment: jsfiddle check it  check it please

Comment: If you are trying to fix a div on page scrolling, you can check this : http://stickyjs.com/ . Hope this helps

Comment: @morodeer you fixed thanks :D

Comment: @morodeer i'll be glad to check your as an answer please do not let answer myself :P

Comment: @sbaaaang , okay, now you can check it =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you're doing it wrong. For detecting scroll position you should use `$(window).scrollTop()`, not `$('html').scrollTop()`

Answer (score 0):

Using $('body').scrollTop() worked for me in Chrome & FF

Comment: nope i fixed it was $(window) not $(html) or body ;) , thanks anyway